# Textbook has different order of commands: login password password-value and also password password-value login Does the order matter?

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-ios, cisco-commands

Textbook has different order of commands: login password password-value

and also password password-value login

Does the order matter?

Cisco switch

Comment: What are we talking here? What type of equipment?

Comment: And what textbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean something like this:

```
line vty 0 15
 logging synchronous
 exec-timeout 15 0
 password <PASSWORD>
 login
 transport input telnet
!
```

or something like this:

```
line vty 0 15
 logging synchronous
 login
 exec-timeout 15 0
 password <PASSWORD>
 transport input telnet
!
```

then, no, it doesn't matter. Most commands in IOS can be entered in any order within the context. If you are in the particular mode (interface, line, router, etc.) then you can usually enter commands in any order for that mode. There are a few exceptions.